# Error SQL syntax with query Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this problem with Java using MySQL.

```
PreparedStatement paisyprovincia_BBDD = bd.prepareStatement("SELECT id=? FROM tabla=? WHERE ? = ?");

paisyprovincia_BBDD.setString(1, "id");
paisyprovincia_BBDD.setString(2, "pais");
paisyprovincia_BBDD.setString(3, "paisnombre");
paisyprovincia_BBDD.setString(4,country.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Returns this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''pais' WHERE 'paisnombre' = 'Australia'' at line 1

where is the problem? thanks for the answers

Comment: Is `tabla` the name of your table? Don't think it accepts a variable for the table you are querying.

Comment: Also, whats the query like you want to execute against the database?

Comment: No, tabla is the variable, the name of the table is 'pais', or i am wrong?

Comment: What about the second question?

Comment: You should use it directly then, no need to put it as parameter. `SELECT id FROM pais p WHERE p.paisnombre = ?`

Comment: As suggested, I don't think you can supply a parameter value for the table name (and similarly I think the same applies to the column name in the `WHERE` clause: you can't set `paisnombre` via a paramter). Also, the first parameter doesn't make sense: you end up with `SELECT id='id' FROM ...`.

Comment: Your SQL does not seem right (which is what the error tells you) - can you explain to us (in SQL terms) what statement are you trying to run. Also, what is the name of the table you are trying to run the query against?

Comment: The query in this case is 
"SELECT id FROM pais WHERE paisnombre = "Australia" ";

Comment: So surely the only thing that is parametrized there is `"Australia"`. Everything else should just be hard coded.

Comment: If you're using normal SQL this should be equivalent to: `SELECT id FROM pais WHERE paisnombre = ?` or HSQL: `SELECT id FROM pais WHERE paisnombre = :paisnombre`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need

```
PreparedStatement paisyprovincia_BBDD = bd.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM pais WHERE paisnombre = ?");    
paisyprovincia_BBDD.setString(1,country.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
```

If you want to use variables for the names of the columns, you can do that at the "Java level", rather than the "SQL level". The point here is that the JDBC driver will (potentially) precompile the SQL you provide and reuse a compiled native database query; it can't do that if the column name will change. So you could do:

```
private List<String> getValuesFromDB(String columnName) {

    String sql = String.format("SELECT %s FROM pais WHERE paisnombre = ?", columnName);

    PreparedStatement paisyprovincia_BBDD = bd.prepareStatement(sql);    
    paisyprovincia_BBDD.setString(1,country.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());

    // execute etc...
}
```

Comment: ok, so i cant use the name of the column as a variable? because i want to re-use the code later and change the column that returns or the column that i use in WHERE, you can understand?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot  James

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your SQL statement:

```
bd.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM pais WHERE paisnombre = ?");
paisyprovincia_BBDD.setString(1, country.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: ok, so i cant use the name of the column as a variable? because i want to re-use the code later and change the column, i dont know if I explain very well

Comment: If you need to retrieve another column just change the SQL, as James stated in the question's comments, just the parameters should be variables, everything else should be hard-coded.

Comment: Oh, okey, thanks a lot!